# How to keep the file in filepond input when i delete it with remove and upload buttons

Tags: laravel-livewire, filepond

I would like to have an input with filepond with instand upload. Then when i press delete i want the file to stay in the input with gray color and the remove and upload buttons like when i set in options instandUpload: false. Can anyone help me?

```
<div
    wire:ignore
    x-data
    x-init="
        FilePond.setOptions({
            credits: false,
            allowMultiple: {{ isset($attributes['multiple']) ? 'true' : 'false' }},
            server: {
                process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort, transfer, options) => {
                    @this.upload('{{ $attributes['wire:model'] }}', file, load, error, progress);
                    console.log(file);
                },
                revert: (filename, load) => {
                    @this.removeUpload('{{ $attributes['wire:model'] }}', filename, load);
                },
            },
        });
        const test = FilePond.create($refs.input);
    "
>
    <input type="file" x-ref="input">
</div>
```

Comment: This is not possible, there is a lot of FilePond logic to change to achieve this.